# Have AMD GPU output to one display, and integrated Intel to another

Tags: graphics, xorg, display, amd-graphics, gpu

So i have my main display plugged into an AMD GPU (Radeon R9 380), everything working fine. I also have another GPU (integrated from intel i5 4430 CPU), and another display. I want to plug my second display to this integrated GPU so i dont waste the computing power of my main GPU.
I know it was possible under windows so it should be under linux as well. Any clues how can I do it?

edit:
If I plug both displays to AMD GPU, the main one shows the boot screen instead the second one. This makes me to think, that propably Intel GPU is run, but it is not used by XORG.